# OnBoard Microphone (P8Z77-V LK) has a lot of static

Tags: audio, microphone, noise, audio-recording, on-board-peripheral

Recently my SoundBlaster has been acting up and my PC would occasionally BSOD with a STOP 124 message. I am trying to rule out or confirm it is my SB by removing it from my PC and using onboard audio for a few days. Hopefully that will get rid of STOP 124 errors.

When I switched to the onboard audio, I noticed that my microphone has a lot of static in the background when voice chatting in a game. People do hear my voice, but there is just this fairly loud static in the background. This has not been happening with my SB, the mic was recording clearly. Mic boost is at minimum (zero). Any idea how to fix it, or whats causes the static?

My MoBo is P8Z77-V LK.

PS: I've done some research and the internet suggests this is normal for onboard audio. Not sure why this is normal though. Playback for recording works perfectly fine with no noise.